# Failed to list files Error in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am Bulk Loading the data into cassandra using SSTables.I am following https://github.com/SPBTV/csv-to-sstable this.

I created the SSTables by

```
 $ java -jar csv-to-sstable.jar quote /home/arque/table_big.cql /home/arque/Documents/data.csv /home/arque
```

I am getting an error while I am trying to run following command:

```
 $ sstableloader -d 192.168.0.7 /home/arque/quote/table_big
```

**Error:**

`Error: Established connection to initial hosts
   Opening sstables and calculating sections to stream
   Failed to list files in /home/arque/quote/table_big
   java.lang.AssertionError
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to list files in /home/arque/quote   /table_big
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.lifecycle.LogAwareFileLister.list(LogAwareFileLister.java:77)`

Comment: Is /home/arque/quote/table_big the correct location on the target host?

Comment: @SimonFontanaOscarsson yup. Location is correct.

Comment: This is happening only when my Primary key is composite key.

Comment: What version of Cassandra are you using? 3.0? It looks like the github project uses Cassandra 2.1.

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.11.1 version. I changed the version pom.xml file from 2.1.6 to 3.11.1

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the csv-to-sstable tool. Look at this file: https://github.com/SPBTV/csv-to-sstable/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spbtv/cassandra/bulkload/Bulkload.java

You say you only have an issue when Primary key is composite key. That's because the tool expects primary key to be defined on same lane as column.
Line 66:

```
// Primary key defined on the same line as the corresponding column
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(\\w+)\\s+\\w+\\s+PRIMARY KEY.*");
```

If you change this to suite your needs it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your time but Tool also provides code for multicolumn primary key.



   `// Multi-columns primary key defined on a separate line` 

    `pattern = Pattern.compile(".*PRIMARY KEY\\s*\\(\\s*\\((.*?)    \\).*\\).*");`

Comment: Damn. I was way too quick with that answer, sorry. I would still try to debug the tool to find out if it's getting all the information properly.